# Google Domains fails to redirect https non-www, results in 403

Tags: google, domains, redirects, dns

I have a weird issue with Google Domains not redirecting https and non-www domain.
When I enter `example.org` it correctly redirects to `https://www.example.org`, however when I enter `https://example.org` a 403 Forbidden error comes up.

**@ A** is pointing to 82.199.138.27 
**www CNAME** is pointing to domains.zuk.io 
Settings adjusted according to this Tutorial provided by the CMS company: https://rukzuk.com/en/Tutorials/Publishing/Connecting-your-own-Domain/

I **don't have access** to the `.htaccess` file since the website is hosted by the cms company, I can only change settings in Google Domains.

I've already been in contact with the CMS hosting company (*rukzuk*) and they haven't implemented a redirect for https non-www. Is there anything I can do via Google Domains to fix this issue?

Comment: Google domains is a domain registrar.  If you are using their redirect service, I wouldn't expect it to work with HTTPS.   I've never seen a redirect service from a registrar that could handle that.   You'd need to be able to upload your HTTPS certificate, or they would need to support Let's Encrypt free certificates.

Comment: But to confirm, where are your A records pointing?   Are both your apex records (naked domain) and `www.` records pointing to the same IP address?   Or is one of them pointing to your CMS hosting company and one is pointing to a redirect service.

Comment: And what is this CMS hosting company?  The solution to your problem may involve them.

Comment: Please edit your question with the answers to my questions.  Once you have done so, your question will automatically enter the re-open queue.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question, however you didn't say if your A records for www and no-www are different.   What IP addresses are they pointing to?

Comment: I only have a non-www A record (like they suggested in the Tutorial), namely the one pointing to the IP address, Google Domains won't let me set up an A record for www, but I think the issue is with the non-www record since only the `https://example.com` leads to the server error.